# Dual Boot Windows and Linux using VHD (Virtual Hard Disk)

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, virtual-machine

How to dual boot Windows and linux-debian using VHD, wherein windows installed on physical hard disk and linux on VHD?

Comment: I've recently posted an answer to this on this thread.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309900/deploy-linux-into-and-boot-from-vhd?answertab=active#tab-top